# java mac addresses discovery in local network

Tags: java, network-programming, ip, mac-address, discovery

I am trying to discover the mac addresses of all the computers in a local network.

what I have so far is

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class Network_discovery {

    public static void main()throws Exception{
        for (int i=1;i<254;i++){
            int timeout=1000;
            try{
                String host="192.168.2" + "." + i;
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
                byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
                if (mac != null) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < mac.length; y++) {
                        System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[y], (y < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
                    }
                } 
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException|SocketException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but i get the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at network_discovery.Network_discovery.main(Network_discovery.java:30)
Java Result: 1"

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `NetworkInterface` class is not going to help you here. See the API docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html). It can only access the network interfaces of the machine it is running on.